# Terraform: Reference locals values inside the creation block

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Is it possible to reference another locals value inside the creation of a locals value?

The example below was the smallest and simplest example I could come up with.

```
variable "size" {
  default     = 3
}

variable "infrastructure_version" {
  default = 1
}

locals {
  values = {
    for n in range(var.size) : n => {
      name = "instance_${n + 1}"
      full_name = "test_${name}_v${var.infrastructure_version}"
    }
  }
}
```

When trying to access *name* within the for loop inside the locals block i get the following error:

```
│ Error: Invalid reference
│ 
│   on instances.tf line 13, in locals:
│   13:       full_name = "test_${name}_v${var.infrastructure_version}"
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.
```

**Other attempts:**
(These were desperate attempts with no real likelihood of succeeding)

- `local.values[n].name` which gives `Error: Self-referencing local value`
- `n.name` which gives `Error: Unsupported attribute`
- `self.name` which gives `Error: Invalid "self" reference`

Anyone know if this is possible? Or am I stuck repeating the creation of *name* inside *full_name* as well?

`full_name = "test_instance_${n + 1}_v${var.infrastructure_version}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing variable interpolation every time a value should be used, it's possible to create a local module that acts as a function.
Where you can use local variables and reuse previously created variables.

Short example below, it's better suited when used for more complex and larger applications due to the amount of overhead.

**main.tf:**
From the main module I import the local module that will serve as a function

```
module "instance_conf" {
  source = "./modules"
  count  = var.size

  index = count.index
  infra = var.infrastructure_version
}

locals {
  values = {for idx, val in module.instance_conf: idx => val}  
}
```

I send in index and infra to the module as input. The variable definitions in the other module must be matching those, here you could also provide descriptions if needed.

**modules/func.tf:**

```
variable "index" {
  type = number
}

variable "infra" {
  type = number
}

locals {
  name = "instance_${var.index + 1}"
}

output "name" {
  value = local.name
}
output "full_name" {
  value = "test_${local.name}_v${var.infra}"
}
```

To get the desired output to the main module, calculate values either in the locals block or directly in the output block. When importing this module the values will be available as a list of maps, for each count.index in the main module. `count  = var.size`

The list could look like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "instance_1",
    full_name: "test_instance_1_v1"
  },
  {
    name: "instance_2",
    full_name: "test_instance_2_v1"
  },
  ...
]
```

So in order to use the module output as previous with for_each I converted the list of map objects, to a map with the index of each map object as the key for that object.

```
locals {
  values = {for idx, val in module.instance_conf: idx => val}  
}
```

And now when using local.values it will look like this:

```
{
  "1": {
    name: "instance_1",
    full_name: "test_instance_1_v1"
  },
  "2": {
    name: "instance_2",
    full_name: "test_instance_2_v1"
  },
  ...
}
```

The project structure now looks like this:

```
.
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   └── values_function.tf
```

Hopefully this helps someone else out. When variable interpolation and recreation of a value every time it is used, is not an acceptable answer. Mainly because of the maintainability factor.

Answer (score 1):

Your last attempt is correct. You can't make it different and it works:

```
 full_name = "test_instance_${n + 1}_v${var.infrastructure_version}"
```

Comment: So you are saying it's not possible.
The last example is not correct, it's still duplication of code. It fulfills the purpose in this example that is simplified a lot.

Comment: @kiabso the last example is correct and it's the only way. If you don't like the code duplication, then maybe terraform is not for you and should look for other tool for infrastructure as code.

Comment: It is not possible to use name because name is not a local variable, it is a key/value pair in a variable map and the map does not get assigned till it is generated by the for loop.

Comment: @Marcin I know that it works, even though it's not very convenient. But I am asking for alternatives.
For examples functions, which I have found out is not implemented (yet?). That would have been a good alternative

Comment: @victorm I guess the reason that doesn't work is because the value belong to a map which is not yet constructed. But you can do locals { a = "foo", b = "${local.foo}_bar" }, so therefore it wouldn't be too far fetched that something similar to what I tried to do in my original post would work

Comment: @kiabso There is no alternative. I'm not sure what do you want to do. Every other way will be longer if you want to introduce some local lists.